# Series $\sum a_n$ that is convergent and so is $\sum (-1)^na_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a conditionally convergent series $\sum a_n$ so that $\sum(-1)^na_n$ is convergent but $\sum |a_n|$ is not? I guess we must have possibility of testing all sign-changes for absolute convergence, not only these on the even/odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any only conditionally convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$, then create a new series by inserting zeros between the terms:

$$a_n= \begin{cases}
b_k, & \text{ if $n=2k$} \\ 
0, & \text{ if $n=2k+1$} \\ 
\end{cases}
$$

This means that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$, because the terms where the factor $(-1)^n$ equals $-1$ are actually zero. But of course $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ will still diverge as it will be the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|$, just reaching the value that the latter has after $m$ terms after $2m$ terms.

Answer (score 4):

Take any conditionally convergent series $\sum_k b_k$ and interleave it with $0$'s, so $a_{2k+1} = 0$ and $a_{2k} = b_k$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may take $a_n = \frac{i^n}{n}$. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n$ are convergent but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ is not.

Comment: What is $i$ in series definition?

Comment: @EgorIvanov The imaginary unit.